# cellForRowAtIndexPath: gives incorrect cell bounds in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, uitableview

Before Xcode 9, I had a working tableview where in cellForRowAtIndexPath: I would check if viewWithTag(1) was nil, as a flag for whether or not this cell needed some initial setup. If so, I'd create some views and add them as subviews to the cell's contentView. I would also position these subviews using the contentView's bounds.

After Xcode 9, the positioning of these subviews are all messed up, and I found that when cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, the cell's bounds and the cell's contentView's bounds are not what they should be. Their height is 44 points, which I guess is the default row height. But it should be 100, because in my viewDidLoad I call:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 100
```

I don't know whether this is just a problem I'm experiencing or if its a bug / change in Xcode 9.

Comment: Don't rely on the frame; use constraints and auto layout.

Comment: You should be using a custom cell class to setup the required views. `cellForRowAt` is not the best place to customize a cell's subviews.